# How to give windows full path to golang methods which takes file path as arguments

Tags: go, filepath

All golang methods say `ioutil.ReadFile` understand unix paths but it doesn't take windows path. Is there a way to achieve this in elegant way so that the methods can take both unix and windows path together.

Comment: https://godoc.org/path/filepath that's you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "/" in windows as well.

**Sample code below.**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("D:/temp/main.go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("File contents: %s", content)

}
```

**Output**

```
D:\temp>go run main.go
File contents: package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
)

func main() {
        content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("D:/temp/main.go")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("File contents: %s", content)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use double back slashes like this:

`content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("D:\\temp\\main.go")`